# Gradle is throwing an error while downloading the artifacts

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle, dependencies

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve net.minidev:json-smart:[1.3.1,2.3].
> Required by:
> project :app > project :stripe_payment > com.stripe:stripe-android:10.4.6 > com.stripe:stripe-3ds2-android:1.2.2 > com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:7.8
> Failed to list versions for net.minidev:json-smart.
> Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml.
> Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml'.
> Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

The gradle is not building properly and as a result the program crashes. I have tried all the methods below

- deleting gradle wrapper jar file
- updating the gradle version (Distribution url )
- maven central replacing